# FtpWebRequest returns "The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in"

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I get this error "The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in." while uploading the file using FtpWebRequest.

1. Error occurs only when I transfer the files to path having subfolders, otherwise it perfectly works fine.
2. Uploading large files about 5 to 10 MB, it gets timed out.

   ```
   void FtpTransfer(string siteName, string portNumber, string ftpUser, string ftpPassword, string destPath)
   {
       FtpWebRequest request;
       DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
       string now_string =
           (now.Year).ToString()
           + "_" +
           (now.Month).ToString("0#")
           + "_" +
           (now.Day).ToString("0#");

       foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
       {
           string srcFile = item.ToString();
           lblSource.Text = srcFile;
           Uri uri = new Uri(srcFile);
           string destFile = srcFile.Replace(lblPath.Text, "").Replace("\\\\", "\\").Replace("\\", "/").Replace("www/","");

           Configuration oConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
           int timeout = int.Parse(oConfig.AppSettings.Settings["TimeOut"].Value);

           if (siteName == "mysite1.co.in" || siteName == "sd1.mysite2.net")
               destFile = "ftp://" + siteName + ":" + portNumber + "/" + siteName + "/_test" + destFile; //error here
           else
               destFile = "ftp://" + siteName + ":" + portNumber + "/" + siteName + destFile; //no error
           lblDestn.Text = destFile;

           request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(destFile);
           request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser, ftpPassword);
           request.Timeout = 6000;
           request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
           request.UsePassive = true;
           request.UseBinary = true;
           request.KeepAlive = true;

           // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
           StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(@srcFile);
           byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
           sourceStream.Close();
           request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

           Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
           requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
           requestStream.Close();

           FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

           string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);
           System.IO.StreamWriter w = System.IO.File.AppendText(path + "\\log_" + now_string + ".txt");
           w.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
               + " "
               + srcFile
               + " "
               + destFile
               + " "
               + response.StatusDescription);

           w.Close();

           response.Close();
       }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have already attempted to do the same operation through a standard FTP client.  If not, try that.  I would then use Wireshark to make sure that is the response coming from the server and verify that the credentails are being sent. After that is verified, check with the FTP owner and make sure the server is configured appropriately.

Comment: Yes, I did. Though am not an expert in using wireshark, I saw the User name and password sent correctly and the same response returned from the server.

Comment: If the credentials are being passed, they are either invalid or do not have permissions.  Sounds like an FTP config issue to me.

Comment: If it works fine with FileZilla, how is it possible that the configuration has issues ? How can I check the configuration ?

Answer (score -2):

I do not exactly know the solution for your problem. but some suggestions:

Use `using(...)` on `IDisposable` classes when ever possible. This promotes proper resource releasing and cleanup when you are finished with it. [MSDN: Using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

You use a timeout of `6000` miliseconds, may you should increase it for huge files or use your local variable `timeout` (read from you app settings).

Improved code with `using`:

```
private void FtpTransfer(string siteName, string portNumber, string ftpUser, string ftpPassword, string destPath)
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            string now_string =
                (now.Year).ToString()
                + "_" +
                (now.Month).ToString("0#")
                + "_" +
                (now.Day).ToString("0#");

            foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
            {
                string srcFile = item.ToString();
                lblSource.Text = srcFile;
                Uri uri = new Uri(srcFile);
                string destFile = srcFile.Replace(lblPath.Text, "").Replace("\\\\", "\\").Replace("\\", "/").Replace("www/", "");

                Configuration oConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
                int timeout = int.Parse(oConfig.AppSettings.Settings["TimeOut"].Value);

                if (siteName == "mysite1.co.in" || siteName == "sd1.mysite2.net")
                    destFile = "ftp://" + siteName + ":" + portNumber + "/" + siteName + "/_test" + destFile; //error here
                else
                    destFile = "ftp://" + siteName + ":" + portNumber + "/" + siteName + destFile; //no error
                lblDestn.Text = destFile;

                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(destFile);
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser, ftpPassword);
                request.Timeout = 6000;
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                request.UsePassive = true;
                request.UseBinary = true;
                request.KeepAlive = true;

                // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
                byte[] fileContents;
                using (StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(@srcFile))
                {
                    fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
                }
                request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

                using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                }

                using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);
                    System.IO.StreamWriter w = System.IO.File.AppendText(path + "\\log_" + now_string + ".txt");
                    w.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                                + " "
                                + srcFile
                                + " "
                                + destFile
                                + " "
                                + response.StatusDescription);

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: There is no difference in the response. I still get the same error. Regarding the time, whether it's 6000 or 600000 it responds the same.

Comment: Ok. Some FTP server implementation has a timeout, maybe you must send the `NOP` command to the server. To keep the connection alive during upload/download.

Comment: Can you provide me with sample code to check the NOOP command ?

Comment: Yes. I will do it tomorrow.